# Problems to run Jquery code on button click on my Wizard-step Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, wizard

I am using Wizard-step for my form in a view, My project is on MVC3.

I have a form that is made on 3 steps which means I have three  tags for each step in my form
and two buttons that are following:

```
<p><input type="button" id="next-step" class="next-step-client-val" name="next-step" value="Next" /></p><     
<p><input type="button" value="Back id="back-step" name="back-step"></p>
```

In my first step I have only a bunch of `TextBoxes`, `DropDownlists` and `TextAreas`, second step have alot of client-side functionality, one example is that user can move rows from a table to another one etc.. And I have a  Jquery validation that is following:

```
                var customTbl = $('#CustomPickedTable');
                var has1 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="1"]').is('*');
                var has2 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="2"]').is('*');
                var has3 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="3"]').is('*');
                var has4 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="4"]').is('*');
                if ((has1 === true) && (has2 === true) && (has3 === true) && (has4 === true)) {
                    jAlerts("Saved", "Info");
                } else {
                    jAlert('You have to move atleast one row from each table', "Varning"); ;
                     return false
                }
```

On the 3th step its just a review on what was created and my next-step button submits the form, when a user clicks on it.

What I want to be able to do is that when a user is on the 2th step and clicks on next-step button the jquery validation above should run. With my Wizard-step code I cant do that beacuse it uses next-step button selector for everything. Is there any solutions for this?

I have tried to put my Jquery validation code inside

```
$("#next-step").click(function () {

}
```

But then my jquery validation code run everytime a user clicks on next button, beacuse my tables are shown in the form but hidden, the validation triggers on first step when a user click on next. So that solution didnt work.

This is my Wizard-step Jquery Code and right now I have my Jquery validation in the bottom which means that when im on 3th step and click on next-step button it will validate and then post. But I dont want it to be like that. I want the validation to happen on the 2th step.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {

            $(".wizard-step:first").fadeIn(); // show first step
            // attach backStep button handler
            // hide on first step
            $("#back-step").hide().click(function () {
                var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step
                if ($step.prev().hasClass("wizard-step")) { // is there any previous step?
                    $step.hide().prev().fadeIn(4500);  // show it and hide current step

                    // disable backstep button?
                    if (!$step.prev().prev().hasClass("wizard-step")) {
                        $("#back-step").hide();
                    }
                }
            });


            // attach nextStep button handler       
            $("#next-step").click(function () {

                var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step
                var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
                var anyError = false;
                $step.find("select").each(function () {
                    if (!this.disabled && !validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                        anyError = true;
                    }

                });
                $step.find("input").each(function () {
                    if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                        anyError = true;
                    }

                });

                $("#next-step").click(function () {
                    if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                        anyError = true;
                    }


                });

                if (anyError)
                    return false; // exit if any error found

                if ($step.next().hasClass("confirm")) { // is it confirmation?
                    // show confirmation asynchronously
                    $.post("/wizard/confirm", $("form").serialize(), function (r) {
                        // inject response in confirmation step
                        $(".wizard-step.confirm").html(r);
                    });

                }

                if ($step.next().hasClass("wizard-step")) { // is there any next step?
                    $step.hide().next().fadeIn(4500);  // show it and hide current step
                    $("#back-step").show();   // recall to show backStep button
                }

                else { // this is last step, submit form
                    var selectedQuestions = $("#SelectedQuestions");
                    var selectedCustomQuestions = $("#SelectedCustomQuestions");
                    var currentIds = new Array();
                    var currentText = new Array();

                    $("#CustomPickedTable td[data-question-id]").each(function () {
                        var clickedId = $(this).attr("data-question-id");
                        currentIds.push(clickedId);
                    });
                    $('#CustomPickedTable td[data-attr-id]').each(function () {
                        var ClickedText = $(this).html();
                        currentText.push(ClickedText);
                    });

                    selectedCustomQuestions.val(currentText.join("|"));
                    selectedQuestions.val(currentIds.join(","));

                    var customTbl = $('#CustomPickedTable');
                    var has1 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="1"]').is('*');
                    var has2 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="2"]').is('*');
                    var has3 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="3"]').is('*');
                    var has4 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="4"]').is('*');
                    if ((has1 === true) && (has2 === true) && (has3 === true) && (has4 === true)) {
                        jAlerts("saved", "Info");
                    } else {
                        jAlert('You have to move atleast one row from each table', "Varning"); ;
                    }
                    return false;

                }

            });
```

My html code looks something like this:

```
<div class="wizard-step>

   //step 1 content

</div>
<div class="wizard-step>

//step 2 content

</div>
<div class="wizard-step>

//step 3 content

</div>
<p><input type="button" id="next-step" class="next-step-client-val" name="next-step" value="Next" /></p><     
<p><input type="button" value="Back id="back-step" name="back-step"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better if you detect at which wizard step you are using jquery .index() function. This way you can do the validation in your next step click handler only if you are on second step moving on to the third step. The code would look something like this :

```
 $("#next-step").click(function () {

            var $step = $(".wizard-step:visible"); // get current step
            var stepIndex = $(".wizard-step").index($step); //index returns 0 based index so second step would be 1.

            var validator = $("form").validate(); // obtain validator
            var anyError = false;
            $step.find("select").each(function () {
                if (!this.disabled && !validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                    anyError = true;
                }

            });
            $step.find("input").each(function () {
                if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                    anyError = true;
                }

            });


            if (anyError)
                return false; // exit if any error found
            if(stepIndex == 1) //if you are on second step then validate your table 
            {
               var customTbl = $('#CustomPickedTable');
               var has1 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="1"]').is('*');
               var has2 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="2"]').is('*');
               var has3 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="3"]').is('*');
               var has4 = customTbl.find('td[data-row="4"]').is('*');
               if ((has1 === true) && (has2 === true) && (has3 === true) && (has4 === true)) {
                  jAlerts("Saved", "Info");
               } else {
                  jAlert('You have to move atleast one row from each table', "Varning"); ;
                  return false
               }
            }

            else if ($step.next().hasClass("confirm")) { // is it confirmation?
                // show confirmation asynchronously
                $.post("/wizard/confirm", $("form").serialize(), function (r) {
                    // inject response in confirmation step
                    $(".wizard-step.confirm").html(r);
                });

            }

            if ($step.next().hasClass("wizard-step")) { // is there any next step?
                $step.hide().next().fadeIn(4500);  // show it and hide current step
                $("#back-step").show();   // recall to show backStep button
            }

            else { // this is last step, submit form
                var selectedQuestions = $("#SelectedQuestions");
                var selectedCustomQuestions = $("#SelectedCustomQuestions");
                var currentIds = new Array();
                var currentText = new Array();

                $("#CustomPickedTable td[data-question-id]").each(function () {
                    var clickedId = $(this).attr("data-question-id");
                    currentIds.push(clickedId);
                });
                $('#CustomPickedTable td[data-attr-id]').each(function () {
                    var ClickedText = $(this).html();
                    currentText.push(ClickedText);
                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: Its not possible to move to step 3 with your code, nothing happens when you are on step 2 and click on next :s

Comment: this code aint running: if ($step.next().hasClass("wizard-step")) { }

Comment: You are right I forgot a "return false" statement at the end of the if. It should work now I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could approach this problem by refactoring the code

```
// validate the inputs in a form
// @param {string|object} jquery selector or jquery object
function validateStep (selector){
  var $step = $(selector);
  var validator = $("form").validate();
  var anyError = false;

  $step.find("select").each(function () {
    if (!this.disabled && !validator.element(this)) {
      anyError = true;
    }

  $step.find("input").each(function () {
    if (!validator.element(this)) {
      anyError = true;
    }

  if (!validator.element(this)) { 
    anyError = true;
  }

  return anyError;
}
```

This way you could validate the second step by calling

```
// this works because jquery returns an array of objects
// as a result of the css selector we call it with
// the eq() function accepts an index value that returns
// the jquery object at that position
// see. http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/
validateStep($('.wizard-step').eq(1));
```

Or the first

```
validateStep('.wizard-step:first');
```

Etc

We could incorporate this into your code like this -

```
$('#next-step').click(function (event){
  var $step = $('.wizard-step');

  if(validateStep($step.filter(':visible'))){
    // go to the next step
    if ($step.next().hasClass("wizard-step")) {         
      $step.hide().next().fadeIn(4500); 

      $("#back-step").show(); 
    } else {
      // submit form
    }
  }
});
```

NB: You can read more about jQuery selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: What do you mean with // validate the inputs in a form
// @param {string|object} jquery selector or jquery object

Comment: Could you also give me an example on how to use  validateStep($('.wizard-step').eq(1)); ? Thanks!

Comment: Should I have this validatestep inside my  " $("#next-step").click(function () {  " ??